# How to configure jdee for Emacs in Cygwin

Tags: emacs

I have installed all of the Cygwin packages,I can run emacs in one of Cygwin's  terminals xterm.
What bothers me is finding the related path about Emacs.Because the JDEE plugin I want to integrate with Emacs needs to know several paths to include outer packages.Such as where is the path of Emacs's site directory.

And following the JDE User's guide, I was stuck at first step，I can not find the customize-variable 'jde-jdk-registry'

Answer (score 2):

During my several diggings in the related manuals and web info I finally got it clear.
The Emacs's site directory in which plugins package are placed is '/etc/emacs/site-start.d'.
The variable 'jde-jdk-registry' set in 'customize-variable ' is missing because you haven't load the jdee package's lisp path in .emacs init file which is in the cygwin's home directory.Below is my .emacs content:

```lisp
;; Load CEDET
(load-file "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/cedet-1.0/common/cedet.el")

;; Enabling various SEMANTIC minor modes. See semantic/INSTALL for more ideas.
;; Select one of the following.
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)
;;; (semantic-load-enable-guady-code-helpers)
;;; (semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)

;; Set JDEE.
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/jde/lisp"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/cedet/semantic"))

(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/jdee-2.4.0.1/lisp"))

(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/cedet/speedbar"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/elib"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "/etc/emacs/site-start.d/cedet/eieio"))

(require 'jde)

(setq jde-check-version-flag nil)
```